# Download file after url redirect in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, httprequest, http-redirect

I'm trying to understand how I can download a file if the url have a redirect before download it

```
const test = http.get(`https://www.google.com/reporting/downloadFile?id=${report_id}:${file_id}`, {
 'headers': {
   'Authorization': `Bearer ${session.accessToken}`,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 }
}
```

response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Redirecting...</title><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" nonce="o0LtHKT-nIudkJkUvwxj9A">var url = 'https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/ServiceLogin?service\x3ddfa\x26passive\x3d1209600\x26continue\x3dhttps:\/\/www.google.com\/reporting\/downloadFile?id%3D1066411953:4040073312%23__HASH__\x26followup\x3dhttps:\/\/www.google.com\/reporting\/downloadFile?id%3D1234567890:1234567890'; var fragment = ''; if (self.document.location.hash) {fragment = self.document.location.hash.replace(/^#/,'');}url = url.replace(new RegExp("__HASH__", 'g'), encodeURIComponent(fragment));window.location.assign(url);</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=dfa&amp;passive=1209600&amp;continue=https://www.google.com/reporting/downloadFile?id%3D1234567890:1234567890&amp;followup=https://www.google.com/reporting/downloadFile?id%3D1234567890:1234567890"></noscript></head><body></body></html>
```

Anyone have some suggestions?

I'm expecting that after call I'll be able to download the report

Comment: It's not just a redirect that you get, but a redirect to a logon page, although you sent an `Authorization` header. Are you sure you can access this URL with the access token? (The space in `.../downloadFile id=...` looks suspicious to me.)

Comment: I think yes, because if I try to follow this url `https://www.google.com/reporting/downloadFile?id=1234567890:1234567890`, through my app (in NextJS) I can download the report (file .xlsx), but if I try the same thing by server side I'm not able to do and I receive this response

Comment: Is the `Authorization` header also set when you follow the link through NextJS? How?

Comment: Yes of course is given through `session.accessToken`:  `'Authorization': 'Bearer ${session.accessToken}'`